# Marshalling unmanaged unicode string to .net. High chars replaced with question marks

Tags: c#, c++, swig

This may or may not be a SWIG question.

I am trying to return a std::wstring by value from a C++ function to C#.  The returned string has a mixture of plain old English chars and Hebrew chars.  The English chars come through fine, but the Hebrew chars are being converted to the question mark symbol at some point.

I am using SWIG to generate the marshalling code.  Stepping through it all with a debugger, it gets to the following SWIG code...

```
static string CreateWString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]IntPtr cString) {
    string str = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni(cString);
    return str;
}
```

At this point str looks perfect.

Next this is returned to the SWIG-generated C++ code which returns the str as a void*.

Then the void* becomes a .net string again in the calling code.  In the calling code, all the hebrew chars are ? marks.

Any ideas what's causing this?

**Edit:**

Further information

As soon as CreateWString returns to the C++ caller you can see the pointer in the debugger looks to be an ANSI string with ? marks in it.  So it seems that .net is performing some sort of conversion on the string before it returns to the caller.  Does that sound right?  How can I control that?

**Edit 2:**
It seems I need to do MarshallAs on the return type CreateWString to stop .net from converting to a TCHAR type (?)

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough code for me to figure this one out.  However, the question marks indicate an encoding mismatch.  Make sure you are in fact using the proper encodings.  .NET defaults to Unicode, it's possible one may expect a different encoding.  Is it possible the code might be using Ansi with a special codepage?

Comment: This is the C++ code that invokes the .net code above.

`jresult = SWIG_csharp_wstring_callback((&result)->c_str()); 
  return jresult;`

jresult is a void*.  It finally ends up in .net again as a string, but with the ? chars.

The value of str in the code in the question appears to be a well formed .net string.

Comment: @bluedog Can you post a minimal project where you can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the definition of the callback function?

Comment: The callback actually points to directly to CreateWString.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the `CreateWString` definition to:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
static string CreateWString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]IntPtr cString)
```

See the examples in the [MarshalAsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx) documentation.

Comment: This seems like it should be the answer, but there's still no change.  I'll keep trying this though...

Comment: The answer is correct.  It didn't work at first for me because the code is called using a delegate.  I had to change the signature of the delegate to ALSO include the [return: MarshallAs...] part.

Comment: Additionally, I had to add `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` to the DllImport directive in C#.